# file pointer down then over

Tags: python, file-io

**The Task**

I am writing a program in python that running a SAP2000 program by importing a new .s2k file each time into the Sap2000 program, and then a new file is generated from the results of the previous run by the means of exporting the data.

The file is about 1,500 lines containing arbitrary words and numbers. (For a better understanding, see this: http://pastebin.com/8ptYacJz, which is the file I am dealing with.)

I'm required to replace one number in the file. 
That number is somewhere in the middle of line 800.

**The Question**

Does anyone know an efficient way to move down to the middle of line 800 in a file, in order to replace one number?

**What I've Tried**

Regular expressions did not work, because there can be more then one instance of the same number.

So I came up with the solution of templating the file and writing a new file each time with the number to be changed as a template parameter.

This solution does work but the person insists that I can move the file pointer down to line 800, then over to the middle of the line to replace the number.

Here is the only code I have for the problem that takes the file buffer to a line then back up to the beginning when I try to seek over.

```
import sys
import os
#open file
f = open("output.$2k")
#this will go to line 883 in text file
count = 0;
while count < 883:
    line = f.readline()
    count = count+1
#this would seek over to middle of file DOESN'T WORK
f.seek(0,0)
line = f.readline()
print(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: ouch my eyes hurt.  you should format your question and include code to help readers.

Comment: I don't even know how to begin helping asker format this.

Comment: Sorry for sounding a bit dumb, but is the line to be changed always line 800?

Comment: I am basically asking is there anyway in python to go down to line X in a text file then seek over to character X within the line you are on.

Comment: Klaus yes it is, but a number in the middle of the line.

Comment: Why are you using Python, or even a high-level language at all?  Can you use awk or sed, or some other regex search/replace?

Comment: Because python is being used to run the Sap2000 program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.  Consider:

```
f=open('output.$2k','r+')
f.seek(300)
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

This script just changes the 300th character in your ascii file to a newline.  Now the tricky part is that there is no way to know the length of a line in an ascii file short of reading until you get to a newline.  So, locating the particular character in the file at the middle of the 800th line is non-trivial.  However, if you can make guarantees (due to the way the file was written) about the line length, you can calculate the position without any problem.  Also note that replacing `1` with `100` won't work here.  You need to replace 1 character with 1 character.

And just for all the other *NIX users in the world ... please don't put `$` in your filename.  That's just a nightmare...

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but with being on line 800 I will have to seek maybe over 1,000 bytes in the file to get to my desired position, is that very efficient or no?

Comment: seeking is more efficient than reading.  (all seeking does is change the file pointer.  reading changes the file pointer and collects data).  But again, figuring out where to seek to is the problem here.

Comment: Yes, but also is seeking more efficient then just writing a new file with the one line changed using a template? That is the main gripe the person has with my file template solution.

Comment: Well, if you write a new file using a template, you need to read the original file to know what to fill in (don't you?).  I guess I don't understand the purpose of the template here...  If you can get that particular byte and change it, then seeking will be way more efficient.  You're only writing ~1 byte instead of thousands and reading none.  Of course, if the line is only a couple thousand lines long, you're not likely to notice the difference unless you do this over and over and over again.

Comment: We will be running this program about 20 times using a loop, no the original file is all written out in the python code as the template.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i'm not a professional programmer, but my (stupid) approach would be: If it's always line 800, read the file line by line while tracking the line numbers. Write then directly to a new file. Read line 800, change it, write it. Then write the rest. Dumb and  not elegant but it should work-unless i miss something which i probably do. And there goes my meager reputation :D

Comment: The person does not want me to write a new file each time as well, just change the one number in the file and then save the file.

Comment: Won't the use of the linecache module solve that problem? As far as i remember, once having the file in memory, you can address a particular line directly. Would it be posible to change line 800 and then overwrite the original file? Just speculating!

Comment: That will still rewrite the whole file though.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you're right. But anything else is beyond my current skills ;)

Comment: So is there basically any way to do this that makes sense without writing a new file?

Answer (score 0):

No. Read in the line, manipulate it, then write it out to the new file you've previously opened for writing (and have been writing the other lines to, unmodified).

Comment: That is kind of what I have done with the template I made. However they say that is wasteful and can be done in the way with go down to line x and then over x. Maybe I should tell them to do it if it is possible.

Comment: If you're *absolutely certain* that the replacement will be the same size as the original then you can read to the previous line and then seek down the rest of the way, but any change in the file size will require a rewrite of the entire file.

Comment: There may be a change from say the number being 7.0000000 to 8.1 which can change the file size.

Comment: @user1472416 You could change 8.1 to 8.1000000, then you don't have a filesize change ;).

Answer (score 0):

A first thing:

```
#this would seek over to middle of file DOESN'T WORK
f.seek(0,0)
```

this is not true. This seeks to the beginning of the file.

---

To your actual question:

> Does anyone know an efficient way to move down to the middle of line 800 in a file, in order to replace one number?

In general, no. You'd need to rewrite the file. For example like this:

```
# open the file in read-and-update mode
with open("file", 'r+') as f:
  # read all lines
  lines = f.readlines()

  # update 800'th line 
  my_line = lines[799].split()
  my_line[5] = "%s" % my_number # TODO: put in index of number and updated number 
  lines[799] = " ".join(my_line)

  # truncate and rewrite file
  f.truncate(0)
  f.writelines(lines)
```

---

You can do it, if the starting position of the number in the file is predictable (e.g. `number_starting_pos = 1234` from the beginning of the file) and the size of the string representation is also predictable (e.g. `20`). 
 Then you could rewrite the number and make sure you fill up the padding with whitespace again to overwrite any content of the previous entry.
Similar to this:

```
with open("file", 'r+') as f:
  # seek to the number starting position
  f.seek(number_starting_pos, 0)

  # update number field, assuming width (20), arbitrary space-padding allowed
  my_number_string = "%19s " % my_number
  # make sure the string is indeed exactly of the specific size (it may be longer)
  assert len(my_number_string) == 20, "file writing would fail! aborting!"
  f.write(my_number_string)
```

For this to work, you'd need to have a look at the docs of your SAP-thingy, and see if whitespace indeed not matters.

---

However, both approaches are based on a lot of assumptions. Depending on your use case it may easily break your code, e.g. if a line is inserted or even a characters is inserted before the number field.